# Getting multiple checkbox values in android?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

new Android developer here. I'm doing a form that let's users set up some search criteria before searching in a SQLite db. Part of the form includes some checkboxes. How do I go about their values in a "best practice" sense?

I'm used to doing PHP, so I would set up a method that returns an array or object with all the values, and then call that inside the 'onClick' method, but is that also a good idea in Java?

My code looks like this:

```
    // Setup a listener, and event handler for the onClick event of the button
    buttonFind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            String text = "Button clicked";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Context context = getApplicationContext();

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be "calling" anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably better to give more details in your question. You don't show anywhere in your code where you define your checkbox... so i'm going to make some assumptions:

I'll assume that somewhere in your onCreate() method of your activity you have something that looks like this:

```
CheckBox myCheckbox = (Checkbox) findViewById(R.id.my_checkbox);
```

If you want to find out if the checkbox is checked or not from your button's onClick() method (since you posted it above), you can do something like this:

```
boolean isMyCheckboxChecked = myCheckbox.isChecked();
```

Hope that works out for you. Next time try to be more clear in your questions.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I left out some important parts of my code. My concern was wether to take a procedural approach (ie. checking the checkboxes in the onClick method itself), or write a method that checks the checkboxes and returns that data in form of an array or object, which can then be called inside onClick (ie. grouping my logic and making my code more readable). So I guess it's more of a best-practice question :)

Comment: There is no "best-practice" for this. it completely depends on your app. If you have lots of checkboxes, you probably want to have 1 function that takes care of reading all of their states and returns the values bundled up for you in a format you want.

Comment: another approach is to update the checkbox states as they are being checked/unchecked rather than doing it at the end when you click the button (will probably make your application seem more responsive). To do that just make set your `OnCheckedChangeListener` and make a generic one that you set for all your checkboxes. for your implementation of it, you identify the checkbox in question by doing myView.getId() and make a `switch` statement to update the proper data structure that holds all your checkboxes' states for the checkbox that you identified.